# Starting a new thread in each kafka Poll

Tags: java, apache-kafka

In order to improve the performance of my Kafka listener I want to start a new thread inside my listener code

```
@KafkaListener(
  topics = {"#{'${my-topic}'.split(',')}"},
  groupId = "${my-group}",
  containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory1",
  errorHandler = "kafkaPaasErrorHandler")

  public void processmessage(ConsumerRecord<String, MyMessage> consumerRecord){
       new Thread(()->{
           processMessage(consumerRecord)
        }).start();
   }

    private void process(ConsumerRecord<String, MyMessage> consumerRecord) {
    // business logic here
    }
```

Some of the messages are getting missed randomly, Is there a concurrency issue that is being overlooked here?

Comment: You are starting a thread which calls another method (please name the methods a bit different instead of changing the case) and ... what do you want to know? Are you facing any kind of issues, any reason to suppose there are concurrency issues?

Comment: Yes ,Some of the messages are getting missed randomly

Comment: @Count -- that's not likely, and this is not the way to handle this. You should have another process in the same consumer group if you want concurrency. What you're doing is likely to get things processed out of order (unless that doesn't matter at all, in which case, fill your boots).

Comment: @Count from your abstract code, messages should not be skipped. Can you update your question with more specific code, and with description on where you have proof of skipped elements? Then we can dig deeper and explain why